# Lastpass icon is positioned under my own components icon

Tags: html, css, lastpass

Is there an easy fix for this?
The faint lastpass icon is displayed underneath my own icon which looks pretty bad.

[image]

Comment: Change CSS for one of icons. E.g. `input{background-postion: 50% 50% !important}`

Comment: give your own icon a white background

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector to move your own icon to the left.

```
input[style*='background-image: url("data:image/png'].icon {
  left: 40px;
}
```

It's little bit hacky but it gets the job done.

Comment: .icon should be your own icon class and have a position absolute or relative.